# Javascript + Vue error: cannot update value of slider

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, runtime-error

I have two integer variables:

- `$globalData.y` defined as a vue observable in `main.js`, and
- `x` defined in `App.vue`.

I have a slider in `App.vue` bound to `x` (i.e. `v-model="x"`) and I wish for the value of `$globalData.y` to change to the inputted value of the slider, but I'm getting multiple errors.

---

main.js:

```
...
Vue.prototype.$globalData = Vue.observable({
  y: 0,
});
...
```

App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>Value: {{ $globalData.y }}</h2>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="60" value="30" 
    v-model="x" oninput="updateData(x)">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      x: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateData(x){
      this.$globalData.y = x;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

When attempting to change the value of the slider I get a `updateData is not defined` error. If I instead try to update the value direcly via `oninput="this.$globalData.y = this.x"` I get a `Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'y')` error.

Comment: try `@input` instead

Comment: Yes, it's either `@input` or `v-on:input`.  This is how you [listen for events in Vue](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html)

Comment: @Ilijanovic that worked! Feel free to post as an answer (:

Comment: Why not use `v-model="$globalData.y"` directly?

Answer (score 0):

[`v-model`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms) on form elements is shorthand for `@input` + `:value` (props affected might differ, based on type of input). But the idea is ***you can't use both patterns*** on the same form element.

One way to fix the problem would be to use `$globalData.y` directly, in `v-model`:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>Value: {{ $globalData.y }}</h2>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="60" v-model="$globalData.y" />
  </div>
</template>
```

And if you want the component to have an `x` alias for `$globalData.y`, you can write it as a computed getter/setter:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>Value: {{ $globalData.y }}</h2>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="60" v-model="x" />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    computed: {
      x: {
        get() { return this.$globalData.y }
        set(val) { this.$globalData.y = val }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

But I'd argue it's useless, since you could use `$globalData.y` anywhere you'd want to use `x`, right?

---

Side note: `<input>` is a self-closing tag. Not closing it (by ending in `/>`) might cause unexpected layout parsing errors for the content following it. Always use valid markup.